# Entity Framework Identity not changing cookie authentication login path

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I'm running into this issue where I change de LoginPath in my code and it still redirects to "Account/Login"

My code:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Acesso/Index"), //bit that I changed
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
        // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, Usuario>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
    }
 });
```

I took this code from the default MVC Authentication Application in VS2013 and that's the only place that I found to be related to redirecting after unauthorized access. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you got ***WebMatrix.dll*** and/or ***WebMatrix.Data.dll*** in your ***bin*** folder, those two libraries are using SimpleMembership and causing the problem. Even if those libraries are ***NOT REFERENCED*** in any project in solution.